# What misstep am I making in trying to simplify $\frac{18 - \frac 7 {3x}} {\frac 7 {18x} - 3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

> Simplify $\dfrac{18 - \dfrac 7 {3x}} {\dfrac 7 {18x} - 3}$?

I'm having a hard time simplifying this particular expression and am seeking any type of assistance in solving it.

In the expression
$$\frac{18 - \dfrac 7 {3x}} {\dfrac 7 {18x} - 3}$$ I split the problems into two separate entities.

For the numerator, I get $3x$ for the LCD and then rewrite the fraction as $$54x-7\frac 7 {3x}$$  As for the denominator, I get $18x$ for the LCD and then rewrite the fraction as
$$7-\frac{54x}{18x}$$

When I begin to divide, I switch the sign from division to multiplication and swap the numerator with the denominator ($7-\frac{54x}{18x}$ becomes $\frac{18x}{7-54x}$).

The product I get is $$\frac{972x^2-126x}{21x - 162x^2}$$
When I simplify I get $6-6$ which is zero. Is this answer correct?

Comment: You should post your question using MathJax.

Comment: @Ilovemath Peace. Sure, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your method, the numerator $N$ is
$$N=18-\dfrac{7}{3x}=\dfrac{54x}{3x}-\dfrac{7}{3x}=\dfrac{54x-7}{3x}$$
The denominator is
$$D=\dfrac{7}{18x}-3=\dfrac{7}{18x}-\dfrac{54x}{18x}=\dfrac{7-54x}{18x}$$
Thus, the given fraction is
$$F=N÷D=\dfrac{54x-7}{3x}÷\dfrac{7-54x}{18x}$$
$$\implies F=\dfrac{54x-7}{3x}×\dfrac{18x}{7-54x}=\boxed{-6}$$

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be this complicated. multilply the numerator and denominator by $18x$ leaving
$$\frac{18 - \frac 7 {3x}} {\frac 7 {18x} - 3} =\frac{324x- 42} {7  - 54x}=-6$$

obviously you are a middle school student so well done for asking for help

Comment: First, thank you. I recently just learned this method that you utilized but even the professor stated that they don't like it so we strayed away from it. Much appreciated beloved.

Comment: @יהודה What method does your prof prefer? How I see it, this is the most intuitive way

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
As we discussed about technique in another post

$$\dfrac{18 - \dfrac 7 {3x}} {\dfrac 7 {18x} - 3}
=\dfrac{\cancel{54x-7}}{3x }
\cdot
\dfrac{18x}{(-1)(\cancel{54x-7})}
=-6$$

Comment: I have no idea when I see it done it's crystal clear but when I am trying to do it alone, its very challenging.  I'm like "these exercises aren't like the examples given in the book!!!" lol. Once again thank you.

Comment: @יהודה
 Do the LCD thing on the numerator and denominator separately. Then you can multiply the numerator by the inverted denominator.